# Show mysqli table

Tags: php, mysqli

Very basic newbie question please; I've managed to retrieve single fields and pull them through to a webpage; but am really struggling to get my head around what's required to show the contents of a table using mysqli.

I get the sense I'm not using the correct type of loop as I'm only seeing the first record in my table repeating infinitely across the page; so if anyone could provide me with the correct syntax to handle requests of this nature I'd be most grateful.

Many thanks!

```
<?php
require_once ("functions.php");

require_once ("connection.php");

session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Team</title>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- put it on user area pages -->
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Team</h1>
<hr />
<?php

if (logged_in() == false) {
    redirect_to("login.php");
}
else {
    if (isset($_GET['User_ID']) && $_GET['User_ID'] != "") {
        $id = $_GET['User_ID'];
    }
    else {
        $id = $_SESSION['User_ID'];
    }

    // # connect mysql server

    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    // check connection

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} :  {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    // # query database
    // fetch data from mysql database

    $sql = "SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* FROM Users a inner join Teams b on a.User_ID=b.User_ID inner join Players c on b.Team_ID=c.Team_ID WHERE a.User_ID = {$id}";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
        $user = $result->fetch_array();
    }
    else {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    // echo the user profile & team data

    echo "<p>Coach: {$user['Username']}</p>";
    echo "<p>Team: {$user['Team_Name']}</p>";

    // echo the player data in table

    while ($row = $user) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Player_Name"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Position"] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}

// showing the login & register or logout link

if (logged_in() == true) {
    echo '<a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>';
}
else {
    echo '<a href="login.php">Login</a> | <a href="register.php">Register</a>';
}

?>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're fetching the result from `database` only single time with following code.

```
$user = $result->fetch_array();
```

You should use `$result->fetch_array()` in `while` loop to run through all the records of database like this,

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
     while ($row=$result->fetch_array()){
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>" . $row["Player_Name"] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row["Position"] . "</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

So your `while` loop will come inside the `if` condition.

Your final code will look something like this,

```
<?php
require_once ("functions.php");

require_once ("connection.php");

session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Team</title>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- put it on user area pages -->
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Team</h1>
<hr />
<?php

if (logged_in() == false) {
    redirect_to("login.php");
}
else {
    if (isset($_GET['User_ID']) && $_GET['User_ID'] != "") {
        $id = $_GET['User_ID'];
    }
    else {
        $id = $_SESSION['User_ID'];
    }

    // # connect mysql server

    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    // check connection

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} :  {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    // # query database
    // fetch data from mysql database

    $sql = "SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* FROM Users a inner join Teams b on a.User_ID=b.User_ID inner join Players c on b.Team_ID=c.Team_ID WHERE a.User_ID = {$id}";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
         while ($row=$result->fetch_array()){
             echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>" . $row["Player_Name"] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row["Position"] . "</td>";
             echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    // echo the user profile & team data

    echo "<p>Coach: {$user['Username']}</p>";
    echo "<p>Team: {$user['Team_Name']}</p>";
    // Place above couple of codes accordingly. 
}

// showing the login & register or logout link

if (logged_in() == true) {
    echo '<a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>';
}
else {
    echo '<a href="login.php">Login</a> | <a href="register.php">Register</a>';
}

?>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's really helpful! Working perfectly now. Thanks so much for the response!

Comment: Great, Please accept it as correct answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use you while loop as

```
 while ($row=$result->fetch_array){
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row["Player_Name"] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row["Position"] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
```